# How to whitelist an ip range blacklisted by Spamcop

Tags: email, ip, blacklist, dyndns

Our testing team uses email addresses from a domain which is different from the actual site domain. For example, our site is `www.abc.com` and email addresses are belongs to `user_x@xyz.com`.

`www.abc.com` is using `noreply@abc.com` configured with `Dyn` email service (with valid `SPF` and `DKIM` keys).

At the receiving end, `user_x@xyz.com` is configured in `opentransfer` mail service.

Since, repeated mails are sent simultaniously for testing purpose, our IP range is now blacklisted by `bl.spamcannibal.org` and 
`bl.spamcop.net`.

Can someone help me with the steps to whitelist my IP ranges ?

Comment: In addition to Jack's answer, you may also want to look into using smtp-sink (part of the postfix package) on your test servers.  It will act like a real MTA, but will send the test messages to /dev/null.  As to whitelisting, your IP will be de-listed automatically (probably within a week or two) if you cease the behavior that triggered the blacklisting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is you cannot - SpamCop provides no way to remove your IP range from the Blacklist or add yourself to the Whitelist.

You have a few options here:

1) Stop actually sending email for testing purposes, if it is really that numerous. Pipe it to a file or just rely on the logs to test if email is leaving the application. When the emails stop, your reputation should improve slowly.

2) Set up your testing domain as a valid domain, with SPF records and DKIM keys, and only send test emails to valid addresses that will not mark the emails as spam. The "legitimate" traffic may also help to improve your reputation.

As a general rule, try not to spam for any reason. At the end of the day, testing or not, this is spam - it puts mail servers under unnecessary load and a mailbox, somewhere, is probably storing these emails.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the sampcop advisories are here :

https://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/298.html

https://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/405.html